# using a earphone with mic for both headphone and microphone purpose

Tags: sound, microphone, headset

I have a earphone with mic that works well on my android phone and I have been using it as a headphone for my pc for quite some time and it worked great (I need to turn it everytime on in alsamixer tho ), but I want to chat too with the same and it wont show up as an input device (mic). It contains only 1 silver pin so I can't plug it in 2 different jacks and enable both of them differently.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

It should be a TRRS connector then (see wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phone_connector_(audio)#PDAs_and_mobile_phones) 
In case your pc has two separate connectors for sound, one for headphone and another for microphone then you need a splitter (Y) cable like this: http://www.cablechick.com.au/cables/avencore-4-pole-trrs-to-35mm-stereo-mic-splitter-cable-female-to-2x-male.html

You can read some short overview of this topic here: 
Understanding TRRS and Audio Jacks
http://www.cablechick.com.au/blog/understanding-trrs-and-audio-jacks

Comment: Can you please mark it `accepted` if the answer is correct (which I hope is true). Thanks